# Seasonal differencing in Arima function in forecast package in R

Tags: r, time-series, modeling

I just want to ask about the `Arima` function in forecast package. The usage of it is,

```
Arima(x, order=c(0,0,0), seasonal=list(order=c(0,0,0), period=NA),
    xreg=NULL, include.mean=TRUE, include.drift=FALSE, 
    include.constant, lambda=model$lambda, transform.pars=TRUE, 
    fixed=NULL, init=NULL, method=c("CSS-ML","ML","CSS"), n.cond, 
    optim.control=list(), kappa=1e6, model=NULL)
```

My data has trend and seasonality, so I applied seasonal differencing using the codes below,

```
Diff1LogCP <- diff(LogChickenProd, lag = 4, differences = 1)
```

Now, I want to have a model SARIMA(1,1,1). Using the `Arima` function, I'm not sure with the `order` and `seasonal` argument. Since my model is SARIMA(1,1,1), so what I did is,

```
SARIMA111 <- Arima(ChickenProd, seasonal = list(order = c(1,1,1), period = 4))
```

Notice that I ignore the `order` argument before the `seasonal` argument. This is because I'm using a seasonal ARIMA model, and not the ordinary ARIMA. So I use the `seasonal` argument only. Is that correct? Or do I need to include the `order` argument, that makes my new codes be

```
SARIMA111 <- Arima(ChickenProd, order = c(1,1,1), seasonal = list(order = c(1,1,1), period = 4))
```

Or should it be like

```
 SARIMA111 <- Arima(ChickenProd, order = c(1,0,1), seasonal = list(order = c(0,1,0), period = 4))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a SARIMA(0,0,0)(1,1,1)$_4$ model, then ignore the order argument. For the notation, see http://otexts.com/fpp/8/9/

Comment: Oh ok, I will read the link you've given to me. Thank you!